# Call Objective C method from JavaScript (React Native)

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native

I have read over the docs time and time again and can only seem to work out how to send data from Objective C to JavaScript (React Native) via props.

What I want to do though is to trigger and Objective C Method from JavaScript (React Native) at a certain point. A simple example that triggers a method that prints "Hello World" to the console will be enough for me to see how it works.

Comment: Have you seen [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)? It's a pretty straight forward example, let me know if you have any trouble

Comment: Thanks :) That was what I was after.

I kept reading this page: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html